# Card Tragic Slip

Tags: magic-the-gathering

does the -1/-1 placed on a creature trigger the effect on 'Hapatra, Vizier of Poisons'.  The section of the card which states 'When you put one or more -1/-1 counterson a creature'.

Answer (score 0):

No.

A counter is a specific thing; which has no relationship to a creature gaining or losing power and toughness because of effects like Tragic Slip's.